# Synchronize sound stream with video stream

Tags: directshow, multicast, directsound

I'm working on a video/audio conference project and i have the next problem:

1. I record sound with DirectSound and send through the network(multicast) everytime the audio buffer is full(aprox. 200 milliseconds) of pcm raw format.
2. Using the DirectX.Capture project(Code project) i'm sending images through the network(multicast).

You have any ideas how to synchronize these two streams?On Lan i have no problem with synchronization,but i think on the internet will be some problems because of the differences of net speed between peers,routing,etc.

Thank you!

Comment: The whole sync challenge is about proper time stamping on capture side, and matching time stamps on the playback side (buffering and delaying data so that those with equal time stamps are played back together).

Comment: Thank you!This buffering and delaying will be available using UDP?if one sound packet and image packet have the same time stamp,what if the image packet is losed?Would be a solution to record small buffers of avi and send them?The synchronization will be done by MuxFilter?

Comment: UDP does not do any sync. DirectShow normally syncs in renderer filters using proper time stamps. You indicated `DirectShow` tag on the question but nothing on the description tells me you are using DirectShow. Where MuxFilter comes from? It is hard to get it all together.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself better.The DirectX.Capture Project uses DirectShow.Net to provide a good capture method from webcam.But with DirectX.Capture i take only video part because for now i don't know how to record both audio and video in an avi packet to send them to network.And because i don't know how to send small avi packets,i use DirectSound for sound and DirectShow.Net for image.Thank you for your time

Comment: Because you have a zoo of frameworks, it is hard to achieve the goal. You need to capture and time stamp appropriately, so that same time stamp value on sender side on video and audio attribute to good lipsync. Then you will be trying to play back respectively.

Comment: @MihaescuFlorin regarding UDP and sync. What you can do is create a mpeg-ts stream locally, and make sure that is in sync. Than you can simply multicast the mpeg-ts stream using udp. The receiver will use the PTS in the a/v streams to sync playback. Just make sure that you don't split ts-packets over multiple udp packets. This way you don't need rtp or any other transport protocol.

Comment: Hello Wimmel and thanks for the comment!Are you talking about vlclib Wrapper available in .net and many other languages?